# Enterprise Architect - Separate Code Generation header and implementation

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I'm learning Enterprise Architect and so far it seems like a nice tool. That said, I am having a problem with code generation. I'd like generated code to be separated such that the class declaration is in a .h file and implementation is in .cpp files (template classes aside). For example, I'd expect generated code for some class, Foo, to look like:

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        int GetSomeInt();
        void SetSomeInt(int a);

    private:
        int someInt;
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
{
}

int Foo::GetSomeInt()
{
}


void Foo::SetSomeInt(int a)
{
}
```

Instead I get a header file with all of the above code in it, which will obviously cause problems later when I try to use `Foo` in multiple files that all get linked together. How can I tell the tool that I want separate files for class declaration and implementation?

Comment: You don't really want to have a separate translation unit (.cpp) for each class. As long as methods are marked as inline you'll be fine with using them in many translation units. Note that since you haven't supplied the actually generated output it is not possible to tell whether it is fine or not.

Comment: @VTT A fair point. I did not mark anything as inline in my model. For simple getter/setter methods, inline is fine but there will inevitably be some more complex methods that I don't want inlined. I'll work on updating the question with some actual output.

Comment: @VTT unless the `inline` Keyword is generated that **will** cause Problems.

Comment: @CodingHero What is set in your code generation options for c++? Is there a source extension set?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, and? Also note that supplied code in post is not the code generated.

Comment: @CodingHero Also check the code Generation templates in use.

Comment: I think that part of my problem was that my example class had originally been a templated class which generated only a header (as expected). After removing the template I guess something did not get cleared because I still only get a header with all the implementation and a .cpp with a `using` statement. If I create entirely new classes in my model, the code gets generated in .cpp and .h files as expected. So I think that I must have made some newbie mistake somewhere and just don't know enough yet to undo it.

Comment: @CodingHero That might explain the behavior. Though I can't remember ATM where the Information for the header / source file association is actually stored.

Comment: @CodingHero I could try to ping an expert about EA's datamodel who might know how to repair that manually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the offer to look in to it further! It's really not a big deal at this time. I'm just working with a throwaway project in order to get familiar with the tool / decide if it's something I want to use long term so it isn't a big deal if I have to re-make things in order to get the behavior I want.

Comment: @CodingHero Fine then. You may put your observations as an answer though. Could be helpful for future research about the same problem met by anyone else. The guy I had in mind is [reachable here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have any.

Comment: @VTT So better stop leaving unsolicited comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What are you talking about?

Comment: @VTT That your comment wasn't really constructive regarding the actual question of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What is your problem? It is your reply to my first comment that wasn't really constructive regarding the actual question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think Uffe would be more likely to be able to answer, but he doesn't hang around here much, OP would be better off asking on the Sparx forums (please post the answer back here if you get one)

Comment: @Hue But Thomas is the EA data model specialist. He even wrote a book about it. I've got his eMail address anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in that case , maybe, but I haven't seen much activity from him on code generation questions

Comment: @Hue It's more a question where the file associations are stored than code generation per se. I made a short smoke test earlier today, but didn't see it in the file association class properties.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh well, at least want to point out that most ea experts are more active on the forums

Comment: @Hue That's why I invited Thomas Kilian and Geert Bellekens to become active here several years ago. The native EA User Forum is just s**t.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146455/discussion-between-hue-and--).

Answer (score 1):

After some further experimentation trying to respond to comments, I discovered at least part of my problem. The original modeled class I was trying to generate code for was a template class. Even after removing the template, however, all implementations were still generated in the .h file. A .cpp file was also generated but contained only a `using` statement referencing what was in the .h file.

After creating new modeled classes, I found that the "normal" behavior is, in fact, what I expected: class definitions are stored in a .h file and implementation details are in a .cpp file. I also retried creating a template class and then removing the template; again the behavior was as expected. It seems that I must have done something strange to my original class that I haven't figured out how to undo.

Thanks to those who offered comments!